# How to define a constraint that enforces a simultaneous insert of two rows with certain values?

Tags: mysql

I have a data_type table and a data table. The column structure is as follows.

```
data_type    data
=========    ====================
id | type    type_ID | count
---------    --------------------
 1 | a             1 | 50
 2 | b             2 | 100
 3 | c             3 | 30
```

In data_type, types 'a' and 'b' are sets, and they must be added to the data table at the same time, and only one of them cannot be entered.

For example

```
INSERT INTO data (typeId, count)
VALUES (1,50), (2,90) <- O

INSERT INTO data (typeId, count)
VALUES (1,50), (3,100) <- X
INSERT INTO data (typeId, count)
VALUES (1,50) <- X
```

Is there any way to do this with SQL rather than ORM?
I need help.

Below is my current query.
DAO.js

```
const createData = async(userId, a1, a2, typeId, count) => {
  await myDataSource.query(
    `INSERT INTO a (user_id, a1, a2)
  VALUES(?,?,?)`,
    [user_id, a1, a2]
  );

  const typeAndCount = typeId
    .map((type, index) => `((SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()),${type},${count[index]})`)
    .join(",");

  const data = await myDataSource.query(
    `INSERT INTO data (a_id ,type_id, count)
  VALUES ${typeAndCount}`
  );
  return data;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the table definition:

```
UNIQUE(typeId, count)
```

That would prevent any pair of values for those two columns from being inserted a second time.

```
INSERT IGNORE ...
```

would let you "try" to insert it a second time, but silently ignore the second "copy" of the data.  For example,

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO data (typeId, count)
     VALUES (1,50), (3,100)
```

would fail to insert `(1,50)` because it was in the table; then successfully insert the other pair.

**More**

An `INSERT` can have any number of rows.  No constraints can be placed on how the multiple rows compare.

To do what you ask, you might need to write a Stored Procedure that is given two rows, then it decides whether they are "ok".  But it would probably be better to do that in application code.

Your function (not in SQL) would be given an array; it would rummage through the array to decide whether the set of rows is "ok" to insert.  It might also perform the `INSERT`.

Comment: My question intent is that if typeId 1 comes in, 2 must also come in, and I want it to fail if 1 comes in but 2 doesn't.
(Conversely, it is the same case where 2 entered but 1 did not.)
That is, typeId 1 and 2 are unconditional sets, and two rows must be added at the same time.

Is there any solution for this problem too? I need help.

Comment: @ggyoE - I added more.  Bottom line: SQL is not the right place to do that.